# Test if byte is empty in python

Tags: python, byte

I'd like to test the content of a variable containing a byte in a way like this:

```
line = []
while True:
    for c in self.ser.read(): # read() from pySerial
        line.append(c)
        if c == binascii.unhexlify('0A').decode('utf8'):
            print("Line: " + line)
            line = []
            break
```

But this does not work...
I'd like also to test, if a byte is empty:
In this case

```
print(self.ser.read())
```

prints: b'' (with two single quotes)

I do not until now succeed to test this

```
if self.ser.read() == b''
```

or what ever always shows a syntax error...

I know, very basic, but I don't get it...

Comment: what syntax error?

Comment: Could it simply be that you're missing the colon at the end of your if statement? Please paste a complete sample of code that is giving you a syntax error.

Comment: Remeber to ALWAYS include the error message you get. This helps narrowing down the possible solution and pin-point the problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It should be:
if self.ser.read() == "b''"

Comment: @Metareven  I don't think so. `b''` is an empty `bytes`, which is the correct thing to compare against. `"b''"` is a three character `str` (which in Python 2 happens to be the same thing as `bytes`, but we don't know what Python version is in use here).

Comment: Thank you sisanared, the test
`code`if self.ser.read():`code`
To test if the byte is empty works,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your help. The first part of the question was answerd by @sisanared:

`if self.ser.read():`

does the test for an empty byte

The second part of the question (the end-of-line with the hex-value 0A) stil doesn't work, but I think it is whise to close this question since the answer to the title is given.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

If you want to verify the contents of your variable or string which you want to read from pySerial, use the `repr()` function, something like:

```
import serial
import repr as reprlib
from binascii import unhexlify
self.ser = serial.Serial(self.port_name, self.baudrate, self.bytesize, self.parity, self.stopbits, self.timeout, self.xonxoff, self.rtscts)
line = []
while 1:
    for c in self.ser.read(): # read() from pySerial
        line.append(c)
        if if c == b'\x0A':
            print("Line: " + line)
            print repr(unhexlify(''.join('0A'.split())).decode('utf8'))
            line = []
            break
```

Comment: Why not: `if c == b'\x0A':` ?

Comment: Yes, I think it's reasonable

Comment: `while True:
            print("read_line_loop")
            for c in self.ser.read():
                line.append(c)
                print("appended")
                if c == b'\x0A':
                    print("stop condition")
                    print("Line: " + line)
                    line = []
                    break`